# How do I configure Ubuntu Server 10.04 to run in a VM on ESXi?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi

Is there anything special I need to do?

I plan on using it as a LAMP server.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this article:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware

And for increasing performance, see the VMWare Tools link/explanation at the bottom

Comment: That article refers to VMWare Server, not ESXi.

Comment: There isn't anything else special you need to do.

I did find this on the vmware forum:
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/177393

A fella had a problem installing vmware tools on 8.10...

If you use the latest versions you should be A-OK.